# What exactly does "Javascript can be run outside the browser" mean in plain English?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, v8

I'm learning Javascript, and I keep seeing this phrase being used when speakers are explaining NodeJS and the V8 engine in relation to Javascript. I know because of Node, we can run JS "outside of the browser," but what does that mean? Oftentimes, instructors use terms I don't know yet (like "server-side scripting") to explain, which makes it difficult to understand.

From what I know so far, it means that you can use JS like a back-end language..? Whereas "running inside a browser," means you can only code visual/front-end interactions, things only users see. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: You can use JS for building server-side (back-end) applications, mobile applications, desktop applications and command-line interface applications.

Comment: What do you understand by the term "back-end language"? What is unclear about "server-side"?

Comment: @TsvetanGanev don't forget embedded devices :-) although these usually don't use nodejs

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are more or less on the right track.  The V8 engine is what powers both chrome and nodejs.  When used with nodejs, it provides a runtime environment for javascript that allows JS code to be run "outside the browser". Traditionally the only place javascript could run was in a browser that implemented support for ECMAScript (all major browsers).  But then along came node.js, which pulled out the critical v8 engine from chrome, and mixed with LibUV for C++ support, created the first runtime that successfully allowed Javascript to run without a browser to run the code.  With Node.js (and Deno if you are curious) we can implement a variety of "back-end", server-side, code.  Think anything you could program in another language now available to be programmed in Javascript.  Node.js and Express js are absolutely great for running web servers, microservices, and many other services independent from a browser run time environment.

Comment: not "anything you could program in another language", but a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Originally, the ability to process the JavaScript language was something that Netscape added to their browser so that it could process not only HTML and CSS, but also JavaScript. Microsoft followed suit and so did all the other browsers. That's what we call running JavaScript within the browser.

But (as an example) Node.js is a command line runtime that includes the core JavaScript runtime, but extracted from the Chrome browser itself. So, with Node, you have the ability to write and run JavaScript, but you aren't running it inside of a browser and therefore you don't have the Document Object Model (DOM) or the Browser Object Model (BOM) available to you because those are APIs that are native to browsers.

But you do have the core JavaScript language and can create applications that do all sorts of non-browser tasks.

You'll find that many other development environments and tools have similar set ups, where the core JavaScript runtime has been added so that you can develop with JavaScript, but outside of a browser.

Comment: In fact, Netscape added the capability to process JavaScript also to their server. It just didn't catch on, but it was always designed as a general-purpose language.